# I am trying to use sorted by value hashmap to build a tree.

Tags: java

This tree is basic Huffman tree. I want to know how can loop through Hashmap and store it in my tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through HashMap by foreach loop:

```
for (V value: myHashMap.values()) {
//store to tree
}
```

Or if you need the keys of this values:

```
for (K key: myHashMap.keySet()) {
    V value = myHashMap.get(key);
    //store to tree
}
```